# Name conflict with classes under different namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have 'ClassName' defined twice in different namespaces. The structure looks like the following

```
app
  -Folder1
    -Folder2
      -class_name.rb

app
  -Models
    -Folder3
      -class_name.rb
```

When rspec tries to load the classes with

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/**/*.rb"].each { |f| load f }
```

I am getting an exception while trying to load `app/Folder1/Folder2/class_name.rb`:

> Expected app/Folder1/Folder2/class_name.rb to define Folder1::Folder2::ClassName (LoadError)

I have spent a lot of time debugging this. Any help would be really welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that it's defined twice, but rather that the class being defined in `app/Folder1/Folder2/class_name.rb` is not called `Folder1::Folder2::ClassName`

Comment: Its called Folder2::ClassName. There is another file inside folder2 Folder2::ClassName2 which loads fine